# Android reverse curve corner drawable/canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-drawable, android-tablayout, tablayout

Is that possible to create different corner for drawable (or draw over the canvas whatever) like this in Android?

[demo picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkZkB.jpg)

My goals is to become tab layout indicator to look like that picture, I can make tab layout indicator to be a full width by setting **tabIndicatorGravity** to **stretch**.

But I have no idea to complete such as corner and left/top/right margin (look at the pic).

** Edit **
Some icon from the demo picture (like spinner) isn't my point.